# How to pass parameters in Crystal Report

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, crystal-reports

I have store procedure for that procedure, i am sending the parameter values as start date and end date query working fine and crystal report also generating fine but what ever  used start date and end date i have to show in crystal report.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Inside your Stored Procedure, add two more columns to your data and have them filled with the Start Date and End Date values for every row.

Then in your Crystal Report - you will have access to these column values in any of the bands, Header, Detail or Footer.

Comment: but store procedure returning a table which contains one or more rows. if i use that column  it will be repeat right

Comment: Yes thats correct

Comment: its not repeating man .. its working fine , thanq grantly

Comment: You're welcome :)  Enjoy Stackoverflow